# Balance Calculation for leave Application

Tags: c#

I am working on project of staff attandance system in which I have to handle the leave application. Also in the leave application the admin will enter:

- the staff member id
- select the leave type:

  - casual leave
  - Earned leave
- then enter the no. of days of leave (*e.g.*, `1`, `2`)

then the balance is calculated like as:

```
totalsancationedleave = no of days, 
availed leave = availedleave+sancationed leave 
balance = totalbalance - availed leave
```

For the first time when I enter a leave for start member (so total balance = 10) then balance become `10 - 1 = 9`.

But for next time when I reopen the project I start calculation from beginning.

I want that for next time when I enter id and select leave type then it start calculation from the remaining balance which is 9.

How i can do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I suggest taking a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We're here to help as soon as you can show us what code you've written so far, so don't forget to include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)!

Comment: On topic: You need to _persist_ your data. Like in a file or (better) database. For a low entry cost, I'd recommend LiteDB, because it is a local, single-file db, native .Net and has built-in ORM. You should be able to use it pretty quickly. (I am not in any way affiliated to the project, just a happy user)